# Parameterizing the Handler of a sub

Tags: vb.net

I have ten images on my WinForm and I'm trying to handle in one Sub the click of any of the ten images.
The images have the following naming lblPlayer1, lblPlayer2 etc
What I want to do is to call the click event for any of the images that are clicked.

```
Private Sub lblPlayer1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblPlayer(X).Click

End Sub
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub lblPlayers_Click(Byval sender As Object,Byval e As EventArgs) Handles 
lblPlayer1.Click,
lblPlayer2.Click,
lblPlayer3.Click,
etc...

End Sub
```

Or else:

```
SomeSub() handles mybase.load

  For each ctrl as control in {lblPlayer1, lblPlayer2, lblPlayer3, etc...}
      addhandler ctrl.click, adressof lblPlayers_Click
  Next ctrl

End Sub

Private Sub lblPlayers_Click(Byval sender As Object,Byval e As EventArgs)
 ' Stuff Here...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Handles clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) can take a comma-separated list of events, so you could do:

```
Private Sub lblPlayer1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblPlayer1.Click, lblPlayer2.Click, lblPlayer3.Click, lblPlayer4.Click, lblPlayer5.Click, lblPlayer6.Click, lblPlayer7.Click, lblPlayer8.Click, lblPlayer9.Click, lblPlayer10.Click

End Sub
```

That will start to get a little unwieldy. You can also use `AddHandler` to add handlers for each label in the form constructor or the form load event.